# Why is my stack overflowing in Julia?

Tags: algorithm, memory, julia

sorry for this blatent and not very conceptual question, but I am trying to parse a spreadsheet of attributes to find the Pareto set using Kung's algorithm. I'm not sure if I'm misunderstanding the algorithm and I know my julia code is horrible at this point, but I'm not sure how I can improve it so that this actually works. I might be looping infinitely, I overflow on very small cases as well.

The introduction to Kung's algorithm I'm referring to can be found here https://engineering.purdue.edu/~sudhoff/ee630/Lecture09.pdf

I'd really appreciate some help with making my code use less memory (it always fails in the "solve" function) and perhaps function better/more correctly. Kung's algorithm is completely recursive by nature, but I'm sure there are better ways than I'm doing it now. Here's what I have!

---

```
using PyPlot
function read_graph_data(fname)
  f=open(fname)
  arr=readdlm(f, ',', Float64, header=true)
  close(f)
  return arr
end


function solve(data)
  if size(data, 1) == 1 
    return Set(data)
  else 
    T= solve(data[1:convert(Int64, floor(size(data,1)/2))])
    B= solve(data[convert(Int64, ceil(size(data,1)/2)): size(data,1)])
    for (b in B)
        for (t in T)
          if (b.>t == all_true)
            setdiff!(T, b)
            continue
          end
          if b.>t == all_false
            continue
          end
        end
        push!(T, b)
    end
  return T
  end
end

num_obj = 2
all_true = (trues(num_obj))
all_false = transpose(falses(num_obj))
data = first(read_graph_data("Lake-Problem-Reference-Set.csv"))
data[:, 1] *= -1
data = data[:, 1:num_obj]
solve(data)
```

Comment: Help us with comments in your code, please describe what do you want from each line?

Comment: Maybe a way to reproduce your error. A julia notebook and/or a way to get the data